# How to extend from a Color class

Tags: java, class, colors

I have a problem. I made a new class which extends the Color class. However, it gives me an error. Here is the code:

```
public class LabeledColored1 extends Color {

    public Color colour;
    public String nom;

    public LabeledColored1(Color color, String name) {

        colour = color;
        nom = name;
        toString();


    }

    public String toString(){

        return nom; 
    }
}
```

The error: `Implicit super constructor Color() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor.` The only way to get around it is put super() with integer as an argument, but I don't want to use super(). Is there a solution to this? This is a question from the book: The Art and Science of Java. Chapter 10 question 6. I am trying extremely hard to learn Java

Comment: Why don't you want to use `super(int arg)`?

Comment: If I use super(int arg), the program I run will only use that color specified in super(int arg)

Answer (score 6):

[Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#constructor_summary) doesn't have any no-arg constructor hence you have use `super(some arguments)`

because by default compiler calls no-arg constructor of super class

```
public LabeledColored1(Color color, String name) {
      super(); // by default added
      ..
}
```

It should be

```
public LabeledColored1(Color color, String name) {
      super(color.getRed(),color.getGreen(),color.getBlue()); 
      ..
}
```

OR

```
public LabeledColored1(Color color, String name) {
      super(color.getRGB()); 
      ..
}
```

---

If you are not overriding any functionality of existing class then **never extend** it instead use composition.

Read [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle that might help you in this case.

I have a doubt here why are you extending `Color` class where as you already have `Color` object in the class itself.

You are combining both `inheritance` and `composition` in the same class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it only gives me an error.

Comment: Thank you Braj! Thank you the program worked! I want to kick myself in the ass. How did you become so good in programming, I feel so depressed because I couldn't figure such a trival problem

Comment: I have a doubt . why are you extending Color class

Comment: I am teaching myself Java from a book called The Art and Science of Java. After I read each chapter I do all the exercises at the end of each chapter. A question wanted me to make a new class that extends color so I can you use it with JComboBox